# Why are staking rewards still coming to my Daedalus wallet when I moved the funds to a hardware wallet?

Tags: staking, ledger

I recently moved my funds from a Daedalus Wallet that was receiving staking rewards around 18 days ago to a Ledger for cold storage.

My staking rewards are still being sent to my previous wallet, is this just the snapshot doing it's magic?  I ask because I thought the snapshot was only for an Epoch, and it has been happening for 3 Epochs now, nothing bad, I am still receiving my rewards, just curious, thanks!

Ledger still on the Daedalus wallet.

Comment: Did you unstake the ADA in your 'hot' wallet before moving it to the 'cold' wallet? Or initiate an unstaking procedure of any sort in the 'hot' wallet?

Answer (score 6):

You start getting rewards 3 epochs after you first delegate. You will be getting your reward for the next 3 epochs after you move, unless you un-delegate and get back the 2 Ada you initially deposited.

Answer (score 4):

This is due, as you said, to the way Cardano is setup with epochs. Your ADA in your Daedalus wallet were included in a snap shot and then you moved your ADA. Once ADA is included in a snap shot, it takes 1 epoch before it becomes active, and then another epoch for rewards to be calculated, and then its paid out after that epoch (three epoch delay). The rewards that you just received were from the epoch snap shot just prior to you moving your funds. Next epoch the hardware wallet will receive rewards.

Note that if you don't un-stake your Daedalus wallet, you will continue to receive rewards on the small amount still in there. We see this all the time with "ghost" wallets. There are many wallets with a small amount of ADA staked in pools where someone moved their ADA but didn't un-stake the old wallet. Then they got rewards for the next three epochs and those are still sitting there earning small rewards.